# How to define model for associations applied only in single item view?

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data, relationship

I have an API server which has a different listing depending on whether it's pulling all users or a single user, e.g.:

`GET /users/` returns:

```
id: 1
name: Name One
username: nameone

id: 2
name: Name Two
username: nametwo
```

`GET /users/1` returns:

```
id: 1
name: Name One
username: nameone
location: Street 1, City One
devices: [device1, device2]
```

What happens in the single user listing is that associations are made, i.e. my `user` table only has `id`, `name`, and `username`, while `location` and `devices` are separate tables that have a `user_id` column`.

How do I go about defining a model like this in Ember? Do I define all fields and leave them empty for the full listing? Or do I need to change my backend API server in order to adapt it to how Ember works (not ideal)? Ideally, I want to conform my Ember model to the data I'm pulling from the API server, rather than to what's in the database, if that makes sense at all.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should always include the same payload for each user (include devices [or only its ids] in /users and /user endpoints).

Imagine first getting a response for USER_1 from /users (incomplete -  without devices), and then going to /users/1. Ember Data will already have USER_1 loaded, so it won't make a request to your API. USER_1 will be considered already fully loaded. It would be a mess to check which records are partially-loaded (and reload them), and which are fully-loaded.

Unless you have hundreds of devices for each user or more, you shouldn't worry about performance that much. If that was the case why you didn't include devices for /users.

If you really want to include small payload for /users you could send only IDs for devices. This way Ember Data would lazily load devices only when they are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what if a user has 100s of devices? After a conversation on the Slack channel it appears that I can use the "included" parameter provided by the JSON API, and I will need to implement that on my API server (in which case I don't need to change my model on Ember, but just to specify its associations). I suppose that could bridge the tension between the client and the server.

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can try that if it works for you. :)